# Determine if two given regular expressions are equivalent

Tags: javascript, regex

Is there a way to programmatically compare two regular expressions in Javascript and determine if they produce identical matches?

```js
const regex1 = /[0-9]+/;
const regex2 = /\d+/;
const regex3 = /[A-Z]{2}/;
const regex4 = /[A-Z][A-Z]/;

isEquivalentRegExp(regex1, regex2); // true
isEquivalentRegExp(regex2, regex3); // false
isEquivalentRegExp(regex3, regex4); // true
```

I've tried using the `source` attribute and the `toString()` function to do that, but they don't work because they return the regular expression itself as a string.

```js
// Not valid
function isEquivalentRegExp(r1, r2) {
  return r1.toString() == r2.toString();
}
```

```js
// Not valid
function isEquivalentRegExp(r1, r2) {
  return r1.source  == r2.source;
}
```

Comment: No, this would probably be equivalent to the halting problem.